# CSS Responsive Grid - items getting stuck on those with longer height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm building a portion of a portfolio site that displays a 4-column grid with images and their titles using relative units of measurement so that it scales with the browser window's size. Right now it works fine with each .item assigned a property of float:left and max-widths defined as a percentage of the overall #container's width (in this case 1100px or 68.75em). It works fine with the exception of the titles, which go below each image in a span. When one of the titles is longer than the 220px (or 20% of the container) the height increases and the items in the next row will get "stuck" on it.

I can fix this easily using PHP to insert a clear:both div after every 4th div (to effectively make a new "row" in the html) but I plan on using media queries or some other device to reduce the amount of columns to 3, 2 and 1 as the browser window shrinks. It would be easier if I could simply have the rows defined by floating the items. Possible solutions?

Styles:

```
body {
font-size: 100%;
line-height: 100%;  /* Neat */
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#container {
max-width: 68.75em;     /* 1100px */
margin: 40px auto;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
float: left;
    width: 20%;
max-width: 20%;
height: auto;
padding: 2.5%;
background-color: #eee;
}

.item img {
display: block;
    width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.item span {
    width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
margin-top: 1em;
display: block;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="cf"> <!-- "cf" comes from my reset, it's a clear-fix --> 
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/placeholder.png" height="220" width="220" alt="" title="" />
    <span>A Title that is Slightly Longer than the Others</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/placeholder.png" height="220" width="220" alt="" title="" />
    <span>A Title</span>
  </div>
```

... (repeat those divs)

```
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's often better to post your code here (if it's not too lengthy) so that people can instantly appreciate your question. Links are good, but less people click on them.

Comment: I have built the same once, so solution I used was to truncate the length of the title in php, so that it would'nt break out of the margin. Good question though

Answer (score 2):

Possible options:

1. Set the `height` sufficient to cover two line cases
2. `.grid-item { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }`
3. Change the title `span` to a `div`, set `height` and `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I ended up using display: inline-block, vertical-align:top and margin-right: -0.27em; on the children .items as a fix for the white space. Not sure on the exact number for the negative right margin but it seems to hold up for now, at least in Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving it a short title. If that's not possible, you could try

```
.item > span{
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

The images will display appropriately, but the too-long titles will display over the image beneath said title. I don't know if this is acceptable for your needs or not, but you may find it useful.

Comment: Is that ">" a typo or some kind of syntax? I've never seen it before.

Comment: No; the ">" selector only selects [immediate children](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). You don't need it for that CSS to work, I just typed it out of habit.